# Angular - Change observable to non-observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ngrx

Lets say i have observable

```
public myObservable$: Observable<SomeModel> | undefined;
```

and non observable

```
public myNonObservable: SomeModel | undefined;
```

And i am filling it like this

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myObservable$ = ....
}
```

How can i get data from `myObservable$` and copy it to `myNonObservable`? Because thing like map and object assign seems to not work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `subscribe` to an observable. The observable is a stream, that means `SomeModel | undefined` that can change its value by time. When you subscribe to the observable, you read that stream by providing a callback function that is executed, every time a new value arrives in the stream.

```
this.myObservable$.subscribe((model: SomeModel | undefined) => ...)
```

If you subscribe to an observable, you also need to unsubscribe, when you don't need to listen to the observable anymore, e.g. when the component gets destroyed. You can either store the subscription in another member variable, or you use a better way of subscribing to an observable. Angular provides a `async` pipe. This pipe handles the whole subscription/unsubscribe process for you. In your template you can do the following

```html
<my-other-component [model]="myObservable$ | async">
</my-other-component>
```

And in the `OtherComponent` you can define an `@Input` that is directly the model.

```
@Component(...)
export class OtherComponent {
  @Input() model: SomeModel|undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to the observable :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myObservable$ = ....
  this.myObservable$.subscribe(data => {
     this.myNonObservable = data;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.myObservable$.subscribe(data=> {
this.myNonObservable = data;
});
```